# Docker - Using DOCKER_BUILDKIT to pass a token secret during build time

Tags: python, azure, docker, pip

I have a pip installable package that was published using [twine](https://pypi.org/project/twine/) to Azure DevOps artifact.

In my build image I need to download that package and install it with `pip`. So I need to
authenticate against azure artifacts to get it. So I am using [artifacts-keyring](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-keyring) to do so

The pip installable URL is something like this:

```
https://<token>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_packaging/<feed>/pypi/simple/ --no-cache-dir <package-name>
```

Actually I am using `docker image build --build-arg ...` approach to succeed.
My `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.7 as intermediate
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git && \
    wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.10/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0
# dotnet core is required from keyring artifacts-keyring pip package below
# that package is used to authenticate against azure devops.

ARG ARTIFACTS_KEYRING_NONINTERACTIVE_MODE
ENV ARTIFACTS_KEYRING_NONINTERACTIVE_MODE=true

# I created a variable to pass the Azure PAT Token
ARG AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN
ENV AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN=$AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN

RUN \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    # INSTALL artifacts-keyring
    pip install pyyaml numpy lxml artifacts-keyring && \
    # INSTALL THE PACKAGE passing the token on the url
    pip install -i https://$AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_packaging/<feed>/pypi/simple/ --no-cache-dir <package-name>
```

It works and I manage to install my private package via `pip` inside the image I built.

The thing is I heard a more proper approach to pass secrets during build time is [Docker BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information). So I redefined my Dockerfile slightly of this way:

```
#PREREQUIREMENTS APT GET PACKAGES INSTALLED
...

ARG ARTIFACTS_KEYRING_NONINTERACTIVE_MODE
ENV ARTIFACTS_KEYRING_NONINTERACTIVE_MODE=true

# Not sure If i need to define token env variable
ARG AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN
ENV AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN=$AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN

# I mounted the secets on the destination /run/secrets/azdevopstoken in my container
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=azdevopstoken,dst=/run/secrets/azdevopstoken

RUN \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    # INSTALL artifacts-keyring
    pip install pyyaml numpy lxml artifacts-keyring && \

    # HOW CAN I PASS THE SECRET HERE AT THE URL SINCE IT IS SUPPOSED TO BE MOUNTED? 
    # $AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN IS NOT VALID HERE ...
    pip install -i https://$AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_packaging/<feed>/pypi/simple/ --no-cache-dir <package-name>
```

The thing is that my secret is not being mounted and even if I manage to do it, I don't know how to associate it to the URL when pip install is executed:

```
pip install -i https://<SECRETMOUNTED>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_packaging/<feed>/pypi/simple/ --no-cache-dir <package-name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your `RUN --mount` directive is missing a command.

The file to which your secret is mounted is only available during that build step. You need to add a command to the end of that directive to make use of the mounted secret. You can combine your 2 `RUN` directives and add a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) (`$(cat "filename")`) to achieve the desired result.

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=azdevopstoken,dst=/run/secrets/azdevopstoken \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    # INSTALL artifacts-keyring
    pip install pyyaml numpy lxml artifacts-keyring && \

    pip install -i https://"$(</run/secrets/azdevopstoken)"@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_packaging/<feed>/pypi/simple/ --no-cache-dir <package-name>
```

Comment: @bgarcial Put an echo in front of your `pip install` command, and we can see if it the whole command is correct, e.g. `echo pip install -i https://"$(</run/secrets/azdevopstoken)" ...`

Comment: I got this `RUN --mount=type=secret,id=azdevopstoken,dst=/run/secrets/azdevopstoken     pip install --upgrade pip &&     pip install pyyaml numpy lxml artifacts-keyring &&     echo pip install -i https://"$(</run/secrets/azdevopstoken)"@pkgs.dev.azure.com/corporateroot/DataFusr%20FEM-client/_packaging/rhdhv_fem/pypi/simple/ --no-cache-dir rhdhv-fem`

On the other hand, I manage to succeed by using `"$(cat /run/secrets/azdevopstoken)"` instead of the command substitution

Comment: can you see my **UPGRADE**, please? I want to execute this workflow from a ci/cd pipeline where the source file (`azdevopstoken.txt`) which one the secrets came out, shouldn't be present in the repository.

Comment: I see. That's still a command substitution. The image you're using doesn't use bash for the shell though, so `$(<"file")` syntax doesn't work. The syntax you used is equivalent. I've updated the answer. I think your update should probably be a separate question, but the main benefit I see is that passing an argument as plain text would allow a malicious actor to see it in plain text in the process table. Mounting a file doesn't have this issue. There may not be a benefit if you're running this in a GitHub actions pipeline.

Comment: Did you mean perhaps nothing to do from github actions? I see this workaround to encrypt secrets larger than 64KB https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#limits-for-secrets but not sure if address it, because with my first approach `docker image build --build-arg AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN="${{ secrets.AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN }}"  . -t containerregistry.azurecr.io/my-image:preview` it works

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I meant there may not be a benefit to using the `RUN --mount` method from GitHub actions. Your first approach seems fine to me. I'd continue using the `docker image build --build-arg ...` approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228457/discussion-between-bgarcial-and-josh-cooley).